# Finding distance between lat-long saved in points

Tags: c#, google-maps, geographic-distance

I'm saving coordinates of places as `Points` which I get from Google API. I want to compute the distance between two of those points. I tried to use GeoCoordinate class for that, but the class requires lat and long in degrees. Is it possible to convert the points to degrees?

I tried this:

```
var pointA = DbGeography.FromText("POINT (34.061839 -118.133087)", 4326);`
```

But this is throwing the following error:

> Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Longitude and Latitude are in the wrong order. `POINT` requires longitude first and then latitude:

```
DbGeography.FromText("POINT (-118.133087 34.061839)", 4326);
```

(which is probably not the most intuitive order to put lat/lon points...)

Comment: will take a look at it and will get back

Comment: 4326 represents what?

Comment: It is the SRID. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506077(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964707.aspx.

Comment: thanks for the reference URLs . This method will give the air distance between two Geo Locations rt

Comment: That's true. If you want real distances (over the road), you could use Here maps (https://developer.here.com/) or Google maps (https://developers.google.com/maps/)